# Fixing propane heater pilot ignition; spark misfiring?

Tags: heating, heater, propane, pilot-light, gas-burner

So... I've got a pretty old heater somewhat similar to the picture below. It wasn't coming on so I took it apart, cleaned it (it was full of soot, corrosion and clogged) qnd changed the gas regulator (which said "change before 2013." )

Anyway; it now works properly except the pilot (similar to the other image below) sort-of misfires. Not sure if the combustion chamber is crooked forwards or what but when I press the switch, about 75% of the time, the sparker arcs with the combustion chamber instead of over the gas pilot and so obviously it won't come  on. Any ideas on how to fix this? Could using a new  sparker piece fix it or is it more likely to be an aberrant position of the chamber as I said?

I tried covering the bit the spark originates at in heatshrink and for a while it did the trick but now it's failing again (I guess maybr it heated up too much or the heatshrink was too big?)

Any better ideas other than getting a new heater?

[image: Heater]

[image: Pilot ignition]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. My guess is that you need to shrink the real spark gap so the spark doesn't go free-styling elsewhere. That said, small appliance repair is off-topic here. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about small-appliance repair.

Comment: @DanielGriscom yeah, but I haven't found a reliably way to do it. Is there another stack-exchange where I might be able to take this question?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't think of one. Sorry. Perhaps there's a support forum for gas heaters, perhaps based on the manufacturer?